# TS: Return object keys depending on input parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, conditional-statements

I have a following function:

```
function getObject(inputObject, additionalParam1?, additionalParam2? ) {
  const returnObject = {...inputObject }

  if(additionalParam1) { 
    returnObject.additionalParam1 = additionalParam1
  }

  if(additionalParam2) { 
    returnObject.additionalParam2 = additionalParam2
  }

  return returnObject
}
```

It works fine, but the code looks ugly to me, because of all the if statements. I also have a backend validation for the return value and it expects additionalParam1 and additionalParam2 to have the exact correct types or to not be there at all, so to have something like:

```
additionalParam1 = undefined / null
```

inside the returnObject is not an option.

Is there a way to make the code prettier and more readable?

Comment: Like this maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4mob3j2e/

Answer (score 1):

you could consider something like that:

```
function getObject(inputObject, additionalParam1?, additionalParam2?) {
    return {
        ...inputObject,
        ...additionalParam1 ? {additionalParam1} : {},
        ...additionalParam2 ? {additionalParam2} : {}
    }
}
```